# Lua table.insert did not work

Tags: lua, lua-table

So recently I made this code where ill call a function to insert the data into the table, however it did not insert the data but does not return any errors, any problem with this?

```
datas = {}
function AddInfo(Name,Desc,dataser,Func)
table.insert(datas,{Name,Desc,dataser,Func})
end
for i,v in pairs(datas) do
print(i)
end
AddInfo("hw","Print Hello World to console","stringer",function()
print("Hello World")
end)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does insert into the `datas` table. However, you are printing before the `AddInfo` gets called. Place your `for i, v...` loop after the `AddInfo` had a chance to run; and [you'll get your desired](https://eval.in/1032311) insert operation result:

```
datas = {}
function AddInfo(Name,Desc,dataser,Func)
  table.insert(datas,{Name,Desc,dataser,Func})
end

AddInfo("hw","Print Hello World to console","stringer",function()
  print("Hello World")
end)

for i,v in pairs(datas) do
  print(i, v)
end
```